# How to pass android Activity Context to Koin Module?

Tags: android, kotlin, koin

I checked few post but haven't found any query related to my problem.

My use case:

I have Dependency in my Activity which are dependent on the Activities Context and should not be allowed to be given Application Context as that can lead to Memory leak's.

```
single { (activity: Activity) -> 
        MyDependency(activity)
    }
```

if use above solution in my case then it can solve the case for one Dependency but then my activity code will be to responsible to send param for each dependency which need's activity's context (beating the use case of dependency injection)

Is it possible to make some specific koin module's dependent on android activity context while other's on application context?

> if i use androidContext(this) in my Application Class while starting koin then all module's requiring the `Context` will `get()` application Context.

Comment: It's the other way around, application context leak is not an issue since it's alive as long as the application is running. While single with an activity is a smell because that singleton with live forever, with a reference to a dead activity inside.

Comment: @Fabio i don't want the Presenter Object to be alive in memory for whole application life cycle as it belong to presenter's logic .

Comment: I'm also interested in this answer even though I'm getting convinced that koin doesn't support this use. 2 hacks come to my mind. Store the active activity in a singleton like in MyAoplication, or call presenter.setActivity on OnStart.

Comment: Did you find a way???

Comment: Did you test it when you use `androidContext()` it cause memory leak??